# jQuery: ajax event

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseevent

OK here is my code

```
$("#content_Div").ajaxStart(function () {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'wait')
}).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'default')
});
```

this is a fairly simple problem: on ajaxStart the cursor immediately changes to the (wait)hourglass but on ajaxComplete it doesnt change back to defalut untill you move the mouse.

lol dat was my problem but while i was writing this i realized after ajaxComplete if you click it will change back to default, so the only reason cursor changes  immediately on ajaxStart is because you have to double click on a element in the content_Div in order to start the request so the click event is wat is changing the cursor after the ajaxStart event has begun  . so what i want is a way to change to cursor without having to move it or click again.

obviously i want to use the cursor to inform user when request is done.

thanks in advance

for Thomas:

```
function DF() { //Deletes selected File
if (selectedfiles.length == 0) {
    alert("No file slected!");
    return
};
var selectedtxt = (selectedfiles.length == 1) ? "'" + basename(selectedfiles[0]) + "'?" : 'these ' + selectedfiles.length + ' files?';
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + selectedtxt)) {
    $.each(selectedfiles, function () {
        $.post("server/editfile.php", {
            user: user,
            oper: "del",
            path: "../" + this
        }, function (res) {
            if (res) {
                alert(res);
            }
            else LT(dirHistory[current]);
        });
    })
}
```

}

Comment: can you post up your ajax request code... normally if I have a loading screen (or in your case you want to change the mouse cursor) you can just do it in there. Before the ajax is run change the mouse cursor to the `wait` one, then when the function returns to say it has succeeded (normally simply `success: function(){}`) just change it back.

Comment: Thomas i will try that but will the Mouse cursor change AUTOMATICALLY or will you have to click or move mouse in order for the cursor to change

Comment: and i have plenty of different requests instead of editing each one i was hoping for a way to set the ajax events once globally.

Answer (score 1):

It does appear that the user would have to move the cursor before it changes, but in addition to this, there's another problem. If the user moves the cursor off of the `#content_Div` then they cannot see whether the data is loading or not, since the CSS only applies while hovering over that one particular DIV.

A method that would clearly show that data is being fetched, irrespective of what the user does, is to make use of an animated gif, "Loading...." lettering, or both. This solution is also a little less intrusive than changing the user's cursor.

If, when data is requested, you append a loading image to the div where the data will be shown, then this loading image will naturally disappear once the data is loaded. For example:

```
$("#content_Div").ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#content_Div").append('<img src="loading.gif" />');
});
```

In this case ajaxStop isn't needed, since the loaded data replaces the image.

[**Here is a jsFiddle example that makes use of both an image and lettering.**](http://jsfiddle.net/aAjuh/)

[**jsFiddle with multiple buttons and a loading div at the center of the page.**](http://jsfiddle.net/jYULD/)

Answer (score 0):

OK Its been about 5 hours since i posted this question and no one has even made a attempt at answering it yet. So im just gonna post what i have found.

This is a Google chrome and Safari Bug. [chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26723)

In All other Browsers you are able to dynamically change the mouse cursor without the user having to click or move the mouse.

witch defeated what i was trying to do. inform user when request was done, if user takes there hand off mouse and waits for the cursor to change they will be waiting all day and night or until they tried to leave because they taught my webpage was frozen. there is no fix because if you check link above the bug is still Unconfirmed. i found no work around either so this is what i did

```
$("#content_Div").ajaxStart(function () {
    if(!$.browser.safari)//ignores ajaxStart if browser is safari or chrome
    $(this).css('cursor', 'wait')
}).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'default')
});
```

Comment: This is not usual behavior of most web sites - when an AJAX request is  in process some 'loading...' image is usually shown and when the request is done the image disappears. 
BTW: you can download such image for free at http://ajaxload.info/

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do it more elegantly like so:

```
$(function(){  
  $("html").bind("ajaxStart", function(){  
     $(this).addClass('busy');  
   }).bind("ajaxStop", function(){  
     $(this).removeClass('busy');  
   });  
});
```

CSS:

```
html.busy, html.busy * {  
  cursor: wait !important;  
}
```

Source:
http://postpostmodern.com/instructional/global-ajax-cursor-change/